# bash - variable storing multiple lines of file

Tags: file, bash

This is my code:

```
grep $to_check $forbidden >${dir}variants_of_interest;

cat ${dir}variants_of_interest | (while read line; do 
     #process ${line} and echo result
done;
)
```

Thank to grep I get lines of data that I then process separately in loop. I would like to use variable instead of using file **variants_of_interest**.

Reason for this is that I am afraid that writing to file thousands of time (and consequently reading from it) rapidly slows down computation, so I am hoping that avoiding writing to file could help. What do you think?

I have to do thousands of grep commands and **variants_of_interest** contains up to 10 lines only.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to write a file. Simply iterate over the result of grep:

```
grep $to_check $forbidden | (while read line; do 
     #process ${line} and echo result
done;
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked:) I ticked the answer randomly as you and lynxlynxlynx were few seconds apart.

Answer (score 3):

You can just make `grep` pass its output directly to the loop:

```
grep "$to_check" "$forbidden" | while read line; do 
  #process "${line}" and echo result
done
```

I removed the explicit subshell in your example, since it is already in a separate one due to the piping. Also don't forget to quote the `$line` variable to prevent whitespace expansion on use.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working solution. Because you and Lynch were just few seconds apart, I chose the answer randomly.

Comment: Ideally you should pick the best answer as the final one — these two are not identical.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
OIFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'; lines=($(grep $to_check $forbidden)); IFS="$OIFS"
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do echo $(process ${line}); done
```

The first line places the results of the `grep` into the variable array `lines`.

The second line processes the array `lines` placing each line into the variable `line`